# Unexpected Readings on Normal Compiling, But Everything working fine with GDB

Tags: c, linux, gdb, ncurses

I've been trying my program in GDB during the making of my own program but when I run the compiled without -g it gives unexpected results, the problem
results from the 2nd Command Onwards that have less or equal to 4 letters

"Help" ( This case persists with every 4 letter command like stop & exit )

Expected : [With GDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjo4v.png) 
Received : [Without GDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2MzS.png)
Note: This is how Letters are Read

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int curs; /*curs Used for Cursor*/
int Nullpos;
char *cmd;

void ShowCMD()
{
    int Strlen = strlen(cmd) ;
    printw("\nFull Command: %s\n NullPosition = %d\n", cmd, Nullpos);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Strlen ; i++ )
    {
        printw("Char %d : %u %c [] \n",i, cmd[i], cmd[i]);
    }
        printw("Char %d : %u [] \n",Strlen, cmd[Strlen]);
}
int AddNUllChar(char *Str)
{
    int nullpos= 0;
    for(int i = 0; (Str[i] <= 127 && Str[i] >= 0) && i < strlen(Str); i++)
        nullpos = i;
    Str[nullpos + 1 ] = (char)0;
    return nullpos;     
}
int IsInAllowedChars(char c)
{
    if (c >= 32 && c <= 57)
        return 1;
    if (c >= 63 && c <= 90)
        return 1;
    if (c >= 95 && c <= 122)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void srvr_cmd()
{
e:;
    curs = 0;
    cmd = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    char ch;
    while (1)
    {
        if((ch = getch()) == ERR)
            continue;

        if(ch > 127 || ch < 0 || ch == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (IsInAllowedChars((ch)))
        {
            printw("%c", ch,ch);
            cmd[curs] = ch;
            curs++;
        }
    }
    Nullpos = AddNUllChar(cmd);
cm:;
    ShowCMD();          
    free(cmd);
    goto e;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clear();
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    srvr_cmd();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't put loop-invariant `strlen` calls in a loop test.  Move them out of the loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Additionally, your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please re-read what a [mcve] is and [edit] accordingly, so we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: This is a lot of code and it doesn't even show the variable declarations. So it's almost impossible to help you. Most likely the code accesses data outside arrays or data that has already been freed. Run your code with an address sanitizer. It might locate the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Similar sysmptpoms usually indicate UBs

Comment: Ok, I'll follow you instructions, I apologize for this, as I am new to this.

Comment: @0___________ UBs?

Comment: UB = undefined behaviour. Why would you debug your application without the `-g` option? Debug information is crucial for anything gdb does..

Comment: I wasnt Debugging without the -g I was trying it before releasing it in github but gives me this Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is `AddNUllChar()`. I must assume that it is supposed to add the terminating null character to the character array. So when the function is entered, the array is not yet null-terminated. If so, you cannot call `strlen()` because it depends on the null character.

`AddNUllChar()` will have undefined behavior. It all depends on the bytes in `cmd`, which is undefined as `malloc()` does not clear it.

As it stands, `AddNUllChar()` cannot be fixed. Instead, remove it and replace:

```c
Nullpos = AddNUllChar(cmd);
```

with:

```c
cmd[curs] = 0;
Nullpos = curs;
```

Note that `Nullpos` now has a value that is offset by 1 compared to your original version. It now actually points at the array element with the null character.

Comment: Actually ` Nullpos ` was supposed to have that value, but did not realize it was offset, Your solution has fixed my problem !  Thank you.